# What need to change to work my app both 32 bit and 64 bit

Tags: ios, 32bit-64bit

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a.

I came to know that  iOS Apps have to support 64 bit after Feb1st.
My Deployment Target is 5.1. will this affect older Apps.
Shall i need to write seprate code for bot 32 and 64 bits.
Now I am using Xocde6. As I googled need Xcode 5.1 to update to 64 bit.is it not possible to using Xcode 6.
Thank you.

Comment: As of 1 feb you will need to be using Xcode 6 and iOS 8 SDK. If you want to use Xcode 5.1 for now you need to set the deployment target iOS 5.1.1 Which part of the code are you concert about that needs rewriting? Because if you use for example `NSInteger` that will be changed to correct bit size on compile time.

Comment: @rckoenes After Feb1 Apps build using Xocde 5.1 won't be submitted aa?

Comment: No, it is clearly stated in the news article you are linked to.

Comment: k got it. is it necessray to maintain differnt code

Comment: No, I've never done. But I can image that there are time where you might need it. But mostly use `NSInteger` and not `int`